# what is signed/unsigned integer in Solidity?

Tags: integer, solidity, uint, uint32, uint16

I found the following definition about signed/unsigned integers on a Solidity book from Packt:

```
Understanding integers
Integers help in storing numbers in contracts. Solidity provides the following two types of integer:

• Signed integers: Signed integers can hold both negative and positive values.
• Unsigned integers: Unsigned integers can hold positive values along with zero. They can also hold negative values apart from positive and zero.
```

I can understand that signed integers can hold both negative and positive values. Unsigned integers can hold positive values along with zero. In the definition it says that **they can also hold negative values apart from positive and zero**.

What this means? Can unsigned integer hold negative values or not? It's a mistake in the book or I don't get it?

Comment: Im guessing its a mistake as it doesnt make any sense.

Comment: @CathalMF - it's so confusing when learning this for the first time. So it seems like a mistake in the book, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *[Unsigned integers] ... can also hold negative values apart from positive and zero.*

^^ This part is incorrect.

Unsigned means that the number doesn't have a `+` or `-` sign. So it can hold only 0 and positive values.